# Python extract title from URL

Tags: python, string, replace, slice, strip

I am using the following function to try and extract **titles** from a list of web scraped **urls.**

I did look at some SO answers, but notice many suggest avoiding regex solutions. I would like to fix and build on my existing solution, but am happy for additional elegant solutions to be suggested.

**Example url 1**: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bd/Rembrandt_van_Rijn_-_Self-Portrait_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg/220px-Rembrandt_van_Rijn_-_Self-Portrait_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg

**Example url 2:** https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ae/Rembrandt_-_Rembrandt_and_Saskia_in_the_Scene_of_the_Prodigal_Son_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg/220px-Rembrandt_-_Rembrandt_and_Saskia_in_the_Scene_of_the_Prodigal_Son_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg

Code (function) that seeks to extract the title from the url.

```
def titleextract(url):
    #return unquote(url[58:url.rindex("/",58)-8].replace('_',''))
    cleanedtitle1=url[58:]
    title= cleanedtitle1.strip("-_Google_Art_Project.jpg/220px-")
    return title
```

The above has the following effect on the URLs:

Url 1: Rembrandt_-*Rembrandt_and_Saskia_in_the_Scene_of_the_Prodigal_Son*-*Google_Art_Project.jpg/220px-Rembrandt*-*Rembrandt_and_Saskia_in_the_Scene_of_the_Prodigal_Son*-_Google_Art_Project.jpg

Url 2: Rembrandt_van_Rijn_-*Saskia_van_Uylenburgh%2C_the_Wife_of_the_Artist*-*Google_Art_Project.jpg/220px-Rembrandt_van_Rijn*-*Saskia_van_Uylenburgh%2C_the_Wife_of_the_Artist*-_Google_Art_Project.jpg

**The desired output however is:**

**Url 1:** Rembrandt_-_Rembrandt_and_Saskia_in_the_Scene_of_the_Prodigal_Son

**Url 2:** Rembrandt_van_Rijn_-_Saskia_van_Uylenburgh2C_the_Wife_of_the_Artist

What I am struggling with, is removing everything after this: _-*Google_Art_Project.jpg/220px-Rembrandt*-*Rembrandt_and_Saskia_in_the_Scene_of_the_Prodigal_Son*-_Google_Art_Project.jpg for each unique case and also then removing the unwanted characters IF they exist, e.g % in url2.

Ideally, I would also like to get rid of the underscores in the title.

Any suggestions using my existing code with a suitable step by step explanation would be appreciated.

My attempt to remove the beginning has worked:

```
cleanedtitle1=url[58:]
```

But I have tried various things to strip the characters and remove the end, which have not worked:

```
title= cleanedtitle1.strip("-_Google_Art_Project.jpg/220px-")
```

Based on one suggestion, I also tried:

```
return unquote(url[58:url.rindex("/",58)-8].replace('_',''))
```

..but this does not remove the undesired text correctly, just the last 8 characters, but as it is variable this does not work.

I also tried this, to remove the underscores, again - no luck.

```
cleanedtitle1=url[58:]
    cleanedtitle2= cleanedtitle1.strip("-_Google_Art_Project.jpg/220px-")
    title = cleanedtitle2.strip("_")
    return title
```

**My imports so far are:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,url_for #importing flask class
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from urllib.parse import unquote
```

I would be happy to accept a re related answer, for learning purposes, but would ideally also like something that completes what I've already started.

**For answers using BeautifulSoup only, here is the whole code for completeness**
(this would also be very useful for reference)

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,url_for #importing flask class
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from urllib.parse import unquote

app = Flask(__name__) #setting app variable to instance of flask class

@app.route('/') #this is what we type into our browser to go to pages. we create these using routes
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    images=imagescrape()
    titles=(titleextract(src) for src in images)
    images_titles=zip(images,titles)
    return render_template('home.html',images=images,images_titles=images_titles)   

def titleextract(url):
    pos1 = url.rindex("/")
    pos2 = url[:pos1].rindex("/")
    cleanedtitle1 = url[pos2 + 1: pos1]
    title = cleanedtitle1.replace("_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg", "")
    title = title.replace("_", " ")
    return title


def imagescrape():
    result_images=[]
    html = urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rembrandt')
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    images = bs.find_all('img', {'src':re.compile('.jpg')})
    for image in images:
        result_images.append("https:"+image['src']+'\n') #concatenation!
    return result_images
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with your:

```
cleanedtitle1=url[58:]
```

This would work, but it's probably not very robust to hard-code numbers, so let's instead start at the character after the second-to-last "/".

You could do this with regular expressions, but more simply, this might look like:

```
pos1 = url.rindex("/")  # index of last /
pos2 = url[:pos1].rindex("/")  # index of second-to-last /
cleanedtitle1 = url[pos2 + 1:]
```

Although actually, you're only interested in the bit between the second-to-last and the last `/`, so let's change make use of the `pos1` that we found as an intermediate:

```
pos1 = url.rindex("/")  # index of last /
pos2 = url[:pos1].rindex("/")  # index of second-to-last /
cleanedtitle1 = url[pos2 + 1: pos1]
```

Here, this gives the following value for `cleanedtitle1`

```
'Rembrandt_van_Rijn_-_Self-Portrait_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg'
```

Now onto your `strip`. This won't do quite what you want: it will loop over the string you gave it, giving the individual characters in that string, and will then remove *all* occurrences of *each* of those characters.

So instead, let's use `replace`, and replace the string with an empty string.

```
title = cleanedtitle1.replace("_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg", "")
```

We can also then do similarly:

```
title = title.replace("_", " ")
```

Then we end up with:

```
'Rembrandt van Rijn - Self-Portrait'
```

---

Putting it together:

```
pos1 = url.rindex("/")
pos2 = url[:pos1].rindex("/")
cleanedtitle1 = url[pos2 + 1: pos1]
title = cleanedtitle1.replace("_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg", "")
title = title.replace("_", " ")
return title
```

---

### Update

I missed the fact that the URL may contain sequences such as `%2C` that we wish to replace.

These could be done using `replace` in the same way, for example:

```
url = url.replace("%2C", ",")
```

but then you would have to do it for all of the similar sequences that might occur, so it's better to use the `unquote` function available from `urllib`.  If at the top of your code you put:

```
from urllib.parse import unquote
```

then you can do these replacements using

```
url = unquote(url)
```

before the rest of the processing:

```
from urllib.parse import unquote

def titleextract(url):
    url = unquote(url)
    pos1 = url.rindex("/")
    pos2 = url[:pos1].rindex("/")
    cleanedtitle1 = url[pos2 + 1: pos1]
    title = cleanedtitle1.replace("_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg", "")
    title = title.replace("_", " ")
    return title
```

Comment: This is beautifully explained thank you. It nearly works but not quite: For instnace, in one title: Rembrandt van Rijn - Saskia van Uylenburgh%2C the Wife of the Artist the % is still there, but also in others the .jpg remains at the end Rembrandt van Rijn - A Polish nobleman.jpg ..am just working through your answer, thank you

Comment: Okay, that can be fixed with `unquote` function - I'll edit it now.

Comment: Could you leave in your fabulous step by step explanation and just add to it....I did try using unquote but really didn't understand what it was and how it worked (see my question attempt). So any explanations there would also be useful.

Comment: @MissComputing I just added an update at the end and left everything else as-is.

Comment: Thank you - can you add it all together at the end for a quick glance please? and I'll be able to check it

Comment: I added url=unquote(url) at the start of the function. I am still getting outputs like: Rembrandt van Rijn - Rembrandts zoon Titus in monniksdracht (Rijksmuseum Amsterdam).jpg

Comment: Also, if you have any additions for bs4 solution this would be the most perfect, complete answer. Thanks in advance

Comment: About to have to go, but please with your `monniksdracht` example, what is the exact input URL and exact desired output? I might be able to have a quick look. Can't help with bs4 I'm afraid.

Comment: image list is being scraped from this url: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rembrandt'...see my update at the end of the question to show my code (web scraping results). That one would be the image url for that particular image

Comment: Sorry I can't quickly see what URL you have and what output you want. If you add that information here then I'll try to have a look later.

Comment: Thanks. The pattern is explained in the question though. It's always eliminating the last part after the googleart string.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, let me know any questions

```
def titleextract(url):
    title = url[58:]
    if "Google_Art_Project" in title:
        x = title.index("-_Google_Art_Project.jpg")
        title = title[:x] # Cut after where this is.

    disallowed_chars = "%" # Edit which chars should go.
    # Python will look at each character in turn. If it is not in the disallowed chars string, 
    # then it will be left. "".join() joins together all chars still allowed. 
    title = "".join(c for c in title if c not in disallowed_chars)

    title = title.replace("_"," ") # Change underscores to spaces.
    return title
```

Comment: Just going to check to see if it works - could you add very detailed comments to explain each line for learning purposes please? For instance: join (c for c in title)

Comment: Ok, I've edited that one. Anything else you want explained?

Comment: thank you. Again, this NEARLY works - so works perfectly for title1 title2 but then further down, Rembrandt van Rijn - Rembrandts zoon Titus in monniksdracht 28Rijksmuseum Amsterdam29.jpg/220px-Rembrandt van Rijn - Rembrandts zoon Titus in monniksdracht 28Rijksmuseum Amsterdam29.jpg  .... so am still working through it,

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this:

1. If you just want to use the inbuilt python string functions, then you could do it by first splitting everything on the basis of `/` and then stripping the common part across all URL's.

```
def titleextract(url):
    cleanedtitle1 = url.split("/")[-1]
    return cleanedtitle1[6:-4].replace('_',' ')
```

2. Since you are already using a bs4 import you could do it by:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlString, 'html.parser')
title = soup.title.text
```

Comment: Thank you - am just checking answers. Could you leave comments to explain each step comprehensively please?

Comment: I think things are pretty self-explanatory. Let me know what you didn't understand.

Comment: For the bs4 answer - is the htmlString = to the URL and if so how do you pass in the whole list (it's called "images")

Comment: for your first suggestion, it nearly works but not for all instances, and the googleartproject part is still there - Rembrandt van Rijn - Self-Portrait - Google Art Project.

Comment: I'm interested in the BS4 answer.....please could you incorporate into my existing code so I know how to pass in the list of image urls in ....

Comment: see the update with the code for the Bs4 scraping in my question